# WSO2 APIM peer not authenticated

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a WSO2 APIM 4.1.0, deployed in AWS and balanced by the AWS load balancer.
When we try to access to the publisher or devportal console, we have this error:

> [2023-06-05 11:02:23,740] ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
> (<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220)
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
> org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
> (<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220)
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:587)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:289)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:589)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:76)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?] Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
> (<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148) ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_5(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:220)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_7(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:228)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.exec(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:583)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine_0.14.13.jar:?]
> ... 50 more Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.executeRequest(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:572)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:549)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:301)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126) ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_5(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:220)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_7(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:228)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.exec(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:583)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine_0.14.13.jar:?]
> ... 50 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:556)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:175)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
> ~[commons-httpclient_3.1.0.wso2v6.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.executeRequest(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:555)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:549)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:301)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr_0.14.13.jar:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126) ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_5(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:220)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_7(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:228)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> ~[js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.exec(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
> ~[?:?]
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:583)
> ~[org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine_0.14.13.jar:?]
> ... 50 more

The private certificate key is not in the keystore because aws it doesn't allow to download it.
Here is my deployment.toml

> [server] hostname = "$env{AM_HOST}" offset=0 base_path =
> "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
> #discard_empty_caches = false server_role = "default"
>
> [transport.https.properties] proxyPort = 443
>
> [super_admin] username = "admin" password = "$env{ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
> create_admin_account = true
>
> [user_store] type = "database_unique_id"
>
> [database.apim_db] type = "postgre" url = "$env{AM_DB_URL}" username =
> "$env{AM_DB_USERNAME}" password = "$env{AM_DB_PASSWORD}"
> validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
>
> [database.shared_db] type = "postgre" url = "$env{AM_SHARED_URL}"
> username = "$env{AM_SHARED_USERNAME}" password =
> "$env{AM_SHARED_PASSWORD}" validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
>
> [keystore.tls] file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks" type =  "JKS" password =
> "wso2carbon" alias =  "wso2carbon" key_password =  "wso2carbon"
>
> [keystore.primary] file_name =  "$env{AM_PRIMARY_KEYSTORE}" type =
> "JKS" password =  "$env{AM_PRIMARY_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}" alias =
> "$env{AM_PRIMARY_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}" key_password =
> "$env{AM_PRIMARY_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD}"
>
> [keystore.internal] file_name =  "$env{AM_INTERNAL_KEYSTORE}" type =
> "JKS" password =  "$env{AM_INTERNAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}" alias =
> "$env{AM_INTERNAL_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}" key_password =
> "$env{AM_INTERNAL_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD}"
>
> [[apim.gateway.environment]] name = "Default" type = "production"
> provider = "wso2" display_in_api_console = true description = "This is
> a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token
> traffic." show_as_token_endpoint_url = true service_url =
> "https://$env{AM_HOST}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
> username= "${admin.username}" password= "${admin.password}"
> ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099" wss_endpoint =
> "wss://localhost:8099" http_endpoint =
> "http://$env{AM_HOST}:${http.nio.port}" https_endpoint =
> "https://$env{AM_HOST}:${https.nio.port}"
> websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021"
> websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"
>
> [apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway] gateway_labels =["Default"]
>
> [apim.analytics] enable = false auth_token = ""
>
> [apim.jwt] enable = true encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
> generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
> claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims" header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
> signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
> #enable_user_claims = true
> #claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"
>
> [apim.cors] allow_origins = "*" allow_methods =
> ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"] allow_headers =
> ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
> allow_credentials = false
>
> [[event_handler]] name="userPostSelfRegistration"
> subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]
>
> [service_provider] sp_name_regex = "^[\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"
>
> [database.local] url =
> "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
>
> [[event_listener]] id = "token_revocation" type =
> "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler" name =
> "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor" order = 1
> [event_listener.properties] notification_endpoint =
> "https://$env{AM_HOST}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
> username = "${admin.username}" password = "${admin.password}"
> 'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"
>
> [oauth.grant_type.token_exchange] enable = true allow_refresh_tokens =
> true iat_validity_period = "1h"

Comment: Have you imported the Public cert to the client trustore?

Comment: yes, it has a CNAME like http://*.xxxxxx.it

Comment: no other ideas?